# input event not triggering for dynamic fields on pasting in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a form with dynamically generated input fields. While pasting content to the fields I need a preview of the input contents on a div. I am using Angular 11.
Here is my .ts file

```
quickSendForm = this.fb.group({
     parameters: this.fb.array([]),
   })
```

Here is my .html file

```
<form [formGroup]="quickSendForm" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<div>
<mat-form-field>
<textarea matInput placeholder="To number" rows="5" maxlength="1300" name="toNumber" id="toNumber" formControlName="toNumber" ></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let param of parameters.controls; let i=index" class="col-md-3">
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Parameter- {{ i + 1 }} " name="parameter" id="showCustomParameter{{ i + 1 }}" formControlName="parameter">
</mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>--input content here --</div>
```

I am getting the content of toNumber field but not getting for parameter field

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` tag isn't properly closed. But I used template reference to show input value there. Could just as easily use formControl value though.

```html
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput #myInput type="text" placeholder="Parameter- {{ i + 1 }} "
      name="parameter" id="showCustomParameter{{ i + 1 }}"
      formControlName="parameter">
    </mat-form-field>
    

  <div> {{ myInput.value }}</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed it by mistake. But even if the <input> tag is closed it won't work.